# Angular:how to pass backend data, onclick of particular component in ngfor

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am looping a component using ngfor so it has n number of components.

And each component has few attributes and in that one attribute(nickName) will be send onclick of the component by calling a service and getting the response and passed inside the component.

Now when I pass like that the response which I got for the component I clicked is used by all the ngfor components. I want it to be used by that component which I clicked.

```
<company *ngFor="let company of customerGroup; trackBy: trackByItems" [nickNames]="nickNames | async" [company]="company" (click)="fetchNickNames(company.debtorId)"></company>
```

**Component code:**

```
  nickNames: Observable<NickName[]>;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedDataService.customerGroup.subscribe(customerGroup => {
      this.customerGroup = customerGroup;
    });

    this.nickNames = this.sharedDataService.nickNames;
    this.sharedDataService.showNicknameModal.subscribe((data) => this.showNickNamePopUp = data.show)
  }

  fetchNickNames(debtorId,parentShadowDebtorIds,shadowDebtorIds): void {
    const debtorIds = [debtorId];
    this.creditOverviewService.fetchFacilitiesNickNames(this.customerGroup.id, debtorIds).subscribe(
      (nickNameResponse) => this.sharedDataService.changeNickNames(nickNameResponse));
  }
```

**Shared Data service**

```
  private nickNameSource = new ReplaySubject<NickName[]>(1);
  nickNames: Observable<NickName[]> = this.nickNameSource.asObservable();

  changeNickNames(nickName: NickName[]): void {
    this.nickNameSource.next(nickName);
  }
```

Tried different possiblities but so far no luck.

Answer (score 1):

Try subscribing nickname, so when changes come it will update the view.

```
NickName[] nicknameView = [] as [];

ngOnInit() {
// other code ..
// subscribe nicknameView  with nickname observerable
this.sharedDataService.nickNames.subscribe(data => {
            this.nicknameView = data;
        });
}
```

If you need to update the specific component you clicked, you could have used two way binding for nickname and update it on click for the component instead of making it as observable

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is displaying but the response is used in all the ngfor components I want it to be used in the component I clicked.

Comment: If you just need to update the specific component you clicked, you could have used two way binding for nickname and update it on click for the component instead of making it as observable.

Answer (score 0):

As the following code is binding to the same Observable to input property *nickNames* of every company component,

```
<company *ngFor="let company of customerGroup; trackBy: trackByItems" [nickNames]="nickNames | async" [company]="company (click)="fetchNickNames(company.debtorId)"></company>
```

Thus each company component has subscribed to the same observable (using *async* pipe). Hence when the observable emits a value every company component gets updated.

One possible solution is to inject required services in company component and update them directly (without using input property binding) when they are clicked.

Other possible solution is if you don't want to inject services to company component (possibly to keep them light), then you should bind each company component to different observable (by creating an array of such observables) and then emit value from respective observable based on which company component is clicked. Here's how it can be implemented.

**Container Component HTML**

```
<company *ngFor="let company of customerGroup; let i=index; trackBy: trackByItems" 
[nickNames]="nickNamesArray[i] | async" 
[company]="company"
[index]="i"
(updateCompany)="fetchNickNames($event,company.debtorId)">
</company>
```

**Container Component Code**

```
nickNames$: BehaviourSubject<NickName[]>(1); //A BehaviourSubject to get the latest value.
nickNamesArray: Observable<NickName[]>[]; //Observable for each company in CustomerGroup

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.sharedDataService.customerGroup.subscribe(customerGroup => {
      this.customerGroup = customerGroup;
      nickNamesArray = []; //create a new instance for each company in CustomerGroup 
      for(let i=0; i<customerGroup.length; i++){
        nickNamesArray.push(new Observable<NickName[]>());
      }  
    });

    this.sharedDataService.nickNames.subscribe(res => nickNames$.next(res)); //BehaviourSubject subscribed to nickName Observable
    this.sharedDataService.showNicknameModal.subscribe((data) => this.showNickNamePopUp = data.show);
  }

  fetchNickNames(index,debtorId,parentShadowDebtorIds,shadowDebtorIds): void {
    //index parameter is to update company component (with respective index property)
    const debtorIds = [debtorId];
    this.creditOverviewService.fetchFacilitiesNickNames(this.customerGroup.id, debtorIds).subscribe(
      (nickNameResponse) => {
        this.sharedDataService.changeNickNames(nickNameResponse));
        nickNamesArray[index].next(nickNames$.getValue());
      }
    )
  }
```

**Company Component HTML**

```
<button (click)="getNickNames()>Get Nick Names</button>
```

Add a button to *getNickNames* which when clicked emits an event to *fetchNickNames*

**Company Component Code**

```
@Input() nickNames: Observable<NickName[]>
@Input() index: number
@Output() updateCompany: new EventEmitter<number>();

  getNickNames(): void{
    this.updateCompany.emit(index);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem you are facing with is that: 
You are probably using the same `sharedDataService` instance from the ngFor components. Therefore, if the replay subject emits a new value all the other components will be updated because; they are listening same observable which is `nickNames`.

The solution that I'd take at this point is:

Create a Map that holds the replay subjects. Give the keys to components while initializing them.

Service:

```
private nickNameSourcesMap = new Map<string, ReplaySubject<NickNames[]>>();
nickNamesMap$ = new Map<string, Observable<string, Observable<NickNames[]>>();

initialize(key) {
  this.nickNameSourcesMap.set(key, new ReplaySubject<NickNames[]>());
  this.nickNamesMap$.set(key, this.nickNameSourcesMap.get(key).asObservable());
}

changeNickNames(key: string, data: NickName[]) {
   this.nickNameSourcesMap.get(key).next(data);
}

getNickNames(key: string): Observable<NickName[]> {
   return this.nickNamesMap$.get(key);
}

dispose(keys: string[]) {
    //Clear the map values when you are done with the component.
    // use it in ngOnDestroy() of component...
    ...
}
```

Component:

```
constructor(private sharedDataService: SharedDataService){}

@Input() key: string;

ngOnInit() {
  this.sharedDataService.initialize(key);
  this.nickNames = this.sharedDataService.getNickNames(key);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
   this.sharedDataService.dispose(key);
}
```

So to change data you just need to use changeNickNames function with the proper key value.